# How to extract prometheus metrics for urls with path params

Tags: node.js, express, prometheus, metrics, prom-client

I have a Node JS app that has a URL like this:

```
/app/:vehicleNumber/details
```

It takes vehicle numbers dynamically in URL.

The prom-client based metrics API for HTTP calls is returning all the URLs as separate URLs instead of clubbing them as a single URL with vehicleNumber as a variable.

```
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/app/GJ98T0006/details"}
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/app/KA28T6511/details"}
.....
```

I want the count based on a single URL.
e.g.

```
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/app/{var}/details"}
```

It is happening when a UUID is present in the URL but not for vehicle numbers present in the URL.

Comment: What are you using to get the metric per route ? Is it a bundled metric collection logic or did you roll your own ?

Comment: It is bundled one. I am trying to get the count of no of time vehicle details API is called. But I am getting the count for each vehicle URL separately

Comment: Please provide the module you are using. There should be some "URL normalisation" configuration in it you can use to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Express, you likely want something like:

```
let path = null;
if (req.route && req.route.path) {
    path = req.baseUrl + req.route.path;
} else if (req.baseUrl) {
    path = req.baseUrl;
} else {
    /*
     * This request probably matched no routes. The
     * cardinality of the set of URLs that will match no
     * routes is infinite, so we'll just use a static value.
     */
    path = '(no match)';
}
```

`path` will be `/app/:vehicleNumber/details`. The `req.route` part may not be necessary for your use case, but it doesn't hurt -- it comes in to play if you're using `express.Router({ mergeParams: true })` to compose your routes.